# Pygame problems - functionality working, but not visuals

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm trying to make a game with Pygame, and thought I would get a handle on how it works by recreating an existing project. So I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYgyRArKDEs

Although when I try to run the source code provided in the description of the video, I get a blank white screen where the game should be, even though the text in the terminal is correct. The Connect-4 works as it should in terminal, but the Pygame window does nothing but stay empty. (Although I can rescale how big that window is.

See the code in the tutorial, but here is what I'm trying to make work:

```
# Game: Flower Shop // Flower Factory
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import operator as op
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygame


GREEN = (0, 128, 0)

print('----------------------------')

print(os.getcwd())

print('')
print('----------------------------')
print('Welcome to your Flower Shop!')
print('----------------------------')

w, h = 5, 5
garden = [['x' for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]


#print(garden)
#

# print(np.matrix(garden))

# for y in range(w):
#     for x in range(h):
#         print garden[y][x]


for y in range(h):
    print()
    for x in range(w):
        print (garden[y][x], end = ' ')

print()
print()


# w=10
# h=10
# fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
# columns = 4
# rows = 5
# for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
#     img = np.random.randint(10, size=(h,w))
#     fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
#     plt.imshow(img)
# plt.show()


pygame.init()

squaresize = 100
width = w * squaresize
height = h * squaresize

size = (width, height)



def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((h,w))
    return board

def draw_garden(board):
    for c in range(w):
        for r in range(w):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (c*squaresize, r*squaresize, squaresize, squaresize))





pygame.display.set_caption("Flower Breeder")
game_over = False
board = create_board()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
draw_garden(board)
pygame.display.update()


while not game_over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pygame.event.get()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (w, h, width, height))  #This takes: window/surface, color, rect
    pygame.display.update() # This updates the screen so we can see our rectangle

    screen.fill(GREEN)
    pygame.display.update()



# Flowers:
# easy - lilies, cosmos


# TODO: see notes

# TODO: use python to amimate the breeding using pictures to represent the flower pathes
```

Thanks! I just really need to get past this blank screen :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that color values have an alpha channel, so (r,g,b,255)
from pygame docs:

> There was a bug in pygame 1.8.1 where the default alpha was 0, not 255
>   like previously.

this migth be the problem when filling ur display.
And i'm not quite sure about the draw-order, and the double-update

try

```
screen.fill()
pygame.draw.rect()
screen.update()
```